# BigQuery Google timezone conversion

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp-with-timezone

When I try running below query I get timestamp in UTC timezone.

```
select current_timestamp from table;
```

Can you please help me to convert timestamp to get in EST timezone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT STRING(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'America/New_York') AS current_timestamp
FROM dataset.table
```

This converts the timestamps to strings using the New York time zone.

Comment: Thank you, i see the timezone in ETC when datatype is string, can we cast it as timestamp and still have it in EST.

Comment: Timestamps don't encode a time zone. When you return a timestamp in the result of a query, the UI shows the timestamp relative to UTC, but you can change this behavior by casting to a string yourself like I showed.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York')
```

The trick here is in converting TIMESTAMP to DATETIME which is timezone-less to represent timestamp as a just date/time, then convert back to TIMESTAMP but now specifying needed timezone.
Note, BigQuery still will show it as UTC but timestamp value itself will represent value in respective timezone

Comment: @hellow - you are right - this happens when one is answering on go - updated the answer :o)

Answer (score 0):

For more control you can use `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP` (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp)

Example:

`` SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T EST", current_timestamp, "America/New_York") AS current_timestamp_EST FROM `dataset.table` LIMIT 1; ``

Results:

```
|-------------------------|
|  current_timestamp_EST  |
|-------------------------|
| 2020-10-23 18:25:17 EST |
|-------------------------|
```